# Trying to add commas to data labels in ggplots geom_text()

Tags: r, ggplot2, powerbi-desktop

I have created a waterfall chart using R in Power BI. I am trying to add commas to the data labels that I have on my bars. So, one of my bars has a value of 1326, I want it to display as 1,326. The issue seems to be that I also need to remove the decimals on the number as well. Is there a way to both remove the decimals and add in a comma?

Here is what I have for code:

```
 ggplot(dataset, aes(x = Recon_cat,  fill = Increase_or_Decrease_TP ))+
    geom_rect(aes(x =Recon_cat,
     xmin = id - 0.2 ,
      xmax = id + 0.2,  
      ymin = end, 
      ymax = start ),
      alpha=0.95) +

   
   geom_text(x= dataset$Recon_cat, y= dataset$end,  size = 11 / .pt, vjust = "top",label = sprintf("%0.0f", round(dataset$Value, digits = 6))) +
    scale_y_continuous(labels = label_comma())+
    scale_x_discrete(labels = function(Recon_cat) str_wrap(as.character(Recon_cat), width = 8)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = c("Net_PD" = "#54585A", "Net_PUD" = "#A0A0A0", "Decrease" = "#F68D2E", "Increase" = "#0075BC" ))+
    theme(legend.position = "none",axis.title.x=element_blank(),panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white", colour = "white",
                                size = .25, linetype = "solid"),
  panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'solid',
                                colour = "white"), 
  panel.grid.minor = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'dashed',
                                colour = "white"), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) +
                                labs( tag = "MMBOE")
```

Data set looks like
[image]

I have tried adding in this to aes in the geom_text section, but it doesnt seem to do anything:

```
aes(label = format(dataset$Value, big.mark = ',' , scientific = FALSE) )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it figured out, replaced
label = sprintf("%0.0f", round(dataset$Value, digits = 0))

with

label = format(round(dataset$Value, digits = 0),big.mark=",",scientific=FALSE)

Comment: Another option would be to use `scales::comma(Value)`. Also note that using `dataset$` in `aes()` is bad practice and not recommended. Instead simply use the column name.

Comment: I did try using just the column name, it told me the object didn't exist. I am wondering if that's a Power BI thing.

Comment: Maybe. I just had a look at you code and realized that you do not use `aes()` but instead pass the vectors directly as arguments which would also not recommend. (: I would do `geom_text(aes(x = Recon_cat, y = end, label = scales::comma(Value)), size = 11 / .pt, vjust = "top")`. I'm not familiar with using R in PowerBI but don't think that this is related to PowerBI as e.g. your geom_rect seems to work fine.

Comment: Thank you for the advice on the edits, I made the change and removed the dataset$ from all variables in that geom_text which seems to be working now, so perhaps it was something else that was causing the error and I just made the wrong assumption! Appreciate the help you have given me!